# Tinymce repeat se duplica

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

Tengo lo sgte:

```
  $scope.tinymceOptions = {
          mode : "specific_textareas",
          editor_selector : "w95",

          height: 100,
          plugins: "textcolor",

          toolbar1: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist | fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor",
........................ }
```

y en mi html:

```
<div ng-repeat="producto in productos">
  <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="area_producto">{{x}}</textarea>
</div>
```

Supongamos que tengo 2 productos, en vez de salirme 2 textarea, se duplica y me salen 2 por cada producto